PoE hat for PI 5
I have a poe hat (b) made by waveshare for my rpi 3/4. I really like it because of the oled display that outputs the IP adreess,cpu temps and things like that. My question is, is it compatible with the rpi 5? I don't know enough about electricity to know and I really don't want to potentially sacrifice my rpi 5 to find out. Any fiance guidance would be appreciated.

It won't work.
While it may be electrically compatible the pin layout on the Pi5 is different.
